# Plot electric and magnetic field lines in a waveguide

Tags: matlab, telecommunication

I was reading a pdf about electromagnetic propagation in different waveguides, and I was wondering how these kind of plots as shown in the picture can be visualized in MATLAB.

[image]

I have the solutions of `Ex`,`Ey`,`Hx` and `Hz` for a rectangular waveguide, and I am trying to plot the field lines for TE11 mode. I have tried to use `meshgrid` and `streamslice` but couldn't make it at all.

Comment: [`quiver`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) may be of some interest...

Comment: I thought quiver gives only the arrows?? 
Although my main problem is how to make the equations appropriate for plotting. I mean, they are equations with 2 variables, x and y, and if I use meshgrid, then I can't use them in the same expression, because of their different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

```
% vector Field 2D
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(-10:1:10,-10:1:10,-10:1:10);
syms x y z 
V2(1) = -5*x;
V2(2) = x*y;
V2(3) = 0;
V1sub = subs(V2(1),[x,y,z],{X,Y,Z});
V2sub = subs(V2(2),[x,y,z],{X,Y,Z});
quiver(X,Y,V1sub,V2sub,2)
title('Vector field of V1')
```